# Is there a way to embed a PDF in a webpage so that it is viewable by Chrome running on Android, without using Google Drive?

Tags: html, css, pdf, embed

It's straightforward to embed a PDF on a webpage using

```
<embed src="a.pdf" width="500" height="400" type="application/pdf">
```

But this doesn't work with the Chrome browser when it's running on the Android OS. Is there a way to show a PDF on a webpage even to users who use this browser and OS combination, and which doesn't require the use of Google Drive?

As I understand it, Chrome stopped supporting the embedding of PDFs using code such as the above, some years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome For Android was developed as a fast light browser without the slowdowns of enhanced plug-ins such as PDFium (Foxit based PDF viewing).

There was very simple intent to open the already downloaded PDF from store into Google PDF application.

This may be changing with Chrome Canary version 122, which is currently considered unstable. However it seems to have undertones of yet more Android feature slow down like PDF viewing. So users who frequently interact with PDFs may find it convenient to install and try it as a secondary browser.

Chromium based MS Edge uses a lighter Acrobat PDF engine and thus they had a Chromium based Android Browser with PDF support. Currently that is adding features to bloat it such as PDF copilot. see https://www.windowslatest.com/2023/10/20/microsoft-edge-on-android-tests-big-ai-upgrade-with-pdf-copilot-and-more/

> A lot of people are trying this feature and liking it. It looks like it could be useful for turning long PDFs into short lists or picking out the main ideas.

However when you do a task like translate a PDF page, same as using a cloud PDF viewer, you hand over your soul data control to the deities in the clouds

Comment: Thanks for this. Please excuse my ignorance, but I don't have access to any equipment running Chro-on-Droid. If I put `<a href="http://foo.bar/a.pdf">Link text here</a>`, will Chro-on-Droid prompt those users to download, or maybe just use their devices to download anyway, but in either case allow them to see the document without my having to upload it to a third-party site? I'm OK with that really. If their downloads folders clog up because they do this all the time, that's their problem. I want to let people who browse to my site read the pdf (and download it if they wish) - that's all.